# How to convert to disjunctive normal form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

The formula is: $\lnot((s \lor \lnot p) \land (q \land r))$

and what I've done so far is this:

$\lnot(s\lor\lnot p) \lor\lnot(q\land r) $

$(\lnot s\land p) \lor (\lnot q\lor\lnot r)$

After this step I became really confused as to how to proceed. Especially with the second part '$(\lnot q\lor\lnot r)$'. How to turn this part into a conjunction. I'm not sure what to do. If anyone could provide help in explaining how to do it and if I did anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You are done, the end result is a disjunction of three terms, one of which is a conjunction and the other two are literals.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much for telling me. I was sure there was still another step I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are done, the end result is a disjunction of three terms, one of which is a conjunction and the other two are literals. – [vadim123](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433911/how-to-convert-to-disjunctive-normal-form/1638853#comment2921166_1433911)